Problem classes based on additional memory
Is there a classification of problems based on
how much additional memory (other than input) they would need?
For context: assume we have a multi-tape Turing machine $M$,
with a bounded input tape and a memory tape.
The input tape is bounded by the input size.
Any extra memory that $M$ needs to use
(other than its control automaton)
should only be read from and written on the memory tape.
Given a bound $b(n)$, where $n$ is the input size,
what kinds of problems can $M$ solve such that,
$M$ uses at most $b(n)$ many 'cells' (or bits) of its memory tape?
I'm mainly interested in the cases
where $b$ is constant or depends logarithmically on $n$.

What does it mean formally that any variables must be read and written on the memory tape? How exactly do you force that the work tape is not used to store temporary data?

@VladimirLysikov you're right! Please read the edited version.

Doesn't the usual definition of space-bounded classes look exactly like that? For example, see §4.1 in Arora-Barak, the definition uses a machine with a read-only input tape and counts the space used on other tapes.

@VladimirLysikov I didn't know where to look or read. Thanks for the reference!

This is just the standard definition of space complexity. In particular, logarithmic space is L, and constant space is REG.
